# BIND int/ext views, need to return ext MX to int clients

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, mx-record

Any DNS pros out there? I have a problem that's stumping me.

I have a BIND DNS server that (with views), supports both internal and external DNS. All internal clients look at the internal view for lookups, and the external view is only a secondary. But MX records need to be handled differently between the views. There has to be no MX records on the internal network, but external needs MX records. What I'd like to happen is, if a PC in the internal net does a normal DNS lookup, the internal view provides the result. If the PC does an MX lookup, the internal returns nothing, and I'd like it so if there's no internal MX, it does a lookup on the external view, and returns the external MX result to the internal client.

Is this even possible?

Comment: Nothing comes to mind using bind.  Could you use a script to copy entries from the external zone (either ones that don't exist internally or just the MX records) into the internal zone file?  Or could you put all the internal addresses on a subdomain (internal.mycompany.com)?

Comment: "If the PC does an MX lookup, the internal returns nothing, and I'd like it so if there's no internal MX, it does a lookup on the external view, and returns the external MX result to the internal client." Simply adding the MX to the internal view would easily accomplish the same thing. Why can't you put MX records on the internal view?

Comment: I know it sounds strange, but my boss doesn't want any internal MX records. I don't know why - maybe he just doesn't want to have to edit two files each time an MX changes. So that's the way it has to be. I'm temped in keeping all MX-related stuff on one include file, and link it to both INT and EXT.

Answer (score 0):

This should *not* be an issue.

Outgoing traffic on port 25, smtp, originating from your internal network should be blocked by your firewalls for all email, with the exception of an authorized mail relay.

Internal systems can only send mail using the authorized relay server and that is one you can easily configure to route the mail for your domains correctly, regardless of how DNS is configured.